# Concat different video file types with different fps and resolutions using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, concatenation

This is the command I am using:

```
{"-y", "-i", file1.toString(), "-i", file2.toString(), "-strict", "experimental", "-filter_complex",
                "[0:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v0];[1:v]scale=480x640,setsar=1:1[v1];[v0][0:a][v1][1:a] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1",
                "-ab", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", "-s", "480x640", "-vcodec", "libx264","-crf","27","-q","4","-preset", "ultrafast", rootPath + "/output.mp4"};
```

When file types are similar, in my case `mp4`, and with same `fps 30` and same resolution, `720 x 980`, they do merge properly. But when I try different file types, say AVI, 3gp, mp4, then all with different fps and resolution and the AVI file with no audio, I get following error:

```
ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
  configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/tyry/Videos/1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-03-14 16:22:27
  Duration: 00:01:06.07, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10775 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x540, 10757 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 47.06 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14 16:22:27
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-14 16:22:27
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/sdcard0/tyry/Videos/2018-03-17-11-33-07.mp4.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-03-17 11:33:15
  Duration: 00:00:06.63, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1030 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 426x240, 1013 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 71:40, 33.65 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-17 11:33:15
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 16000 Hz, mono, fltp, 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-03-17 11:33:15
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0xacb60d40] Input link in1:v0 parameters (size 426x240, SAR 1:1) do not match the corresponding output link in0:v0 parameters (960x540, SAR 1:1)
[Parsed_concat_0 @ 0xacb60d40] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_concat_0
Error configuring complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

What is the proper command to concat different file types, with different fps, and different resolution and map audio properly to a set fps and resolution, output being mp4 file?